# How to redirect Sys.err for Library?

Tags: java, api

I'm using a Java Library which is printing out Sys.err messages. I would like to redirect this messages to a log file (but only messages from the Library).

Is this possible?

(used Library: google libphonenumber - https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Comment: You can use [`System::setErr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-) but it will redirect all calls to `System.err`...

Comment: Using a proper logging framework is not an option? Asked differently the library does not support Log4J or something the like?

Comment: @assylias: That's especially what i don't want.

Comment: @Matthias Steinbauer: Not that i know of. How do you mean "proper logging framework"? How could that help me? I've added the library i'm using.

Comment: Maybe you should describe what you want to do. Below the directory `libphonenumber\java\libphonenumber\src` is not a single reference to `System.out` or `System.err`.

Comment: @SubOptimal: You are write, i was to fast at judging just because the console output was red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's libphonenumber uses standard `java.util.logging` based logging. Which is one of the popular logging frameworks available for Java. You can configure the behaviour of the logging with a properties file based configuration. On startup of your application you can specify a parameter that denotes the configuration file:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="logging.properties"
```

In the `logging.properties` file you can then configure the logging behaviour behaviour like this:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.patter=%h/java%u.log
```

Obviously, there are many more configuration options, the example given above is only the bare minimum as required per your question.

For details I strongly recommend reading this excellent intro by Lars Vogel: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html